# Incorrect arithmetic output

Tags: php, mysql

I have this piece of code that inserts marks in to the database, but the problem is that

```
$sql_insert=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `marks_1c` 

(student_name,test_1,test_2,test_3,test_4,test_5,mock,teacher,subject)
VALUES('$student',
       '$test_1',
       '$test_2',
       '$test_3',
       '$test_4',
       '$test_5',
       '$mock',
       '$session',
       '$subject')")or die(mysqli_error($conn)); if($sql_insert){
    $total=($test_1+$test_2+$test_3+$test_4+$test_5)/5;
    $mock_mark=$mock*0.6;
    echo 'Marks entered for '.$student.' '.'average is '.($total*0.4)+($mock_mark);
```

when I run this code, it does not echo the "Marks entered for '.$student.' '.'average is" but it only displays the result of ($total*0.4)+($mock_mark).

But when, I put the multiply the ($total*0.4) and ($mock_mark), it displays the "Marks entered for '.$student.' '.'average is"

i do not understand, please help.

Comment: replace this => **echo 'Marks entered for: '.$student.' average is'.(($total*0.4)+($mock_mark));**

Comment: Thanks @SoniVimal

Comment: check below my answer is it proper for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code will workout

```
$mark = ($total*0.4)+($mock_mark);

echo "Marks entered for ".$student." "."average is".$mark;
```

**or**

```
echo 'Marks entered for '.$student.' '.'average is '.(($total*0.4)+($mock_mark));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
'text' + 4
```

this is mathematical operation. If you want to add some number + number to text you must use () for all result, so in your example will be

```
echo 'Marks entered for '.$student.' '.'average is '.($total*0.4 + $mock_mark);
```

No we are concatenate text with some mathematical result

Answer (score 0):

replace this =>

```
echo 'Marks entered for: '.$student.' average is'.(($total*0.4)+($mock_mark));
```